# How to export components/functions array in JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have array of components and functins that I want to export. current code looks like:

```
const components = [
    Login,
    OtpModal,
    ...]

export {
Login,
OtpModal,
... }
```

but I would like to export components array in one go, so there wouldn't be duplicate lists.
Is it even possible in JS?

Edit:
The array is currently used only for mapping Vue components :

```
components.map(component => Vue.component(component.name, component))
```

So if using objects somehow would accomplish both mapping and export then it would be nice...

Comment: Do you want it to export it as an array only, or `object` can work?

Comment: You can't. Once you store them in `components`, there is no way to get the original names of the containing references anymore (unless they are objects that contain their own names, e.g. using a `name` property).

Comment: It is better to store them as object and construct an array using reduce for instance when needed.